# How to copy the array with array.push() function without duplicate key value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, cart

I am developing a food cart function where I am adding products to the cart. My cart is an Array type and the product is an object with key-values. The problem I am facing is, whenever I am trying to add a new product with a different value for a similar key, it overwrites the value of the same key for the old product as well. As per my understanding, an array is just a reference pointing to my product object but I want to know, what is the best method to resolve this issue? Here is how my code structure looks like:

component.ts

```
this.cartService.add(product); // <- This Product contains key modifier: ["abc","def"]
```

cartService.ts

```
add(product) {
   product.qty = 1;
   product.total = product.price;
   this.cart.push(product);
}
```

So every time I push the product to the cart with a different modifier key (for example -> modifier: ["dfg", "gght"]), it overwrites the existing this.cart array objects with a new value for all modifier keys.

Here is how the two products inside my this.cart array gets logged:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
category: "-M9JfAlqr_JiAiPTugc5"
description: "zxfsfsafas afa fsaff fsf safsa sfaf safs afsafa fas asf safs af aasf asfa asf ."
isAvail: true
key: "-MMWt2wDMVaHqj45eKFg"
modifiers: ["-MLxJCw0s0uDYSXYokz1"]
name: "Single Modifier"
price: 23
qty: 1
selectedModifiers: ["Corn"]  // <- This is initially empty when I added this product but after adding second product this also took the value of second.
total: 23
__proto__: Object

1:
category: "-M9JfAlqr_JiAiPTugc5"
description: "zxfsfsafas afa fsaff fsf safsa sfaf safs afsafa fas asf safs af aasf asfa asf ."
isAvail: true
key: "-MMWt2wDMVaHqj45eKFg"
modifiers: ["-MLxJCw0s0uDYSXYokz1"]
name: "Single Modifier"
price: 23
qty: 1
selectedModifiers: ["Corn"] // <- This is correct but after adding this product, this selectedModifiers value also gets added to first product. See above.
total: 23
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Any idea, how can I resolve this issue optimally?

Comment: Please add reproducable example

Comment: Have you tried `product.selectedModifiers = [youSelectedModifier]`?

Comment: @CaseyC : I did, but it still gives me the same overwritten result :(

Comment: Those two objects look identical to me. Have you tried checking the value of  `product` before you push it to the array?

Comment: They are actually similar as they are same product but I am adding them with different modifiers so inside my cart array they need to be different as the product modifiers are different. For example, a same steak food product can be ordered with different modifier meat temperature. So basically they are steak only but with different meat temperature preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the product object before modifying it

```
   add(product) {
       const clone = {...product} 
       clone.qty = 1;
       clone.total = clone.price;
       this.cart.push(clone);
    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer. If you wish to get clarification use the comments.

Comment: The only other code I have in my cartService is initialization of cart array as "cart = [];"

Comment: It said I needed at least 50 points to add a comment on a question

Comment: Pushing a new item into an array would not override existing items. Pushing would add the element at the next available index. If you however do the need the data overwritten, you can consider looking into  objects or maps

Comment: Check my question again. I added the log of how my this.cart gets logged. Notice "selectedModifiers" key. I have commented alongside.

Comment: I think I see the problem now. The product you pass into the push method of the cart is an object.. And objects retain their references, similar to array. So if you push it the first time, it's qty and price are re-calculated and set on the reference and it is added. If you push it the second time, the qty and price are still recalculated on the same reference, so the first once which has the same reference will be modified as well

Comment: Easiest solution I can think of is to copy the object before any modification is done on it in the add function

Comment: @KevinIzuchukwu: So should I copy the product object to a new object inside my cart service before adding it to the array ?

Comment: Yes, try cloning the object to a new variable to create a new reference before pushing it to the cart. I have updated my answer to show a code sample

Comment: @KevinIzuchukwu: This worked. I created a new tmp object inside add function like let tmp = {...product}; and then added that tmp object into my array and now I have two different modifiers with same product.

Comment: `{...product}` is a bit less verbose for a shallow clone.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I forgot about destructuring.. That works too.. And it is cleaner